# Mat-Checkbox binding model can it be optional or null?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Hi all I am new to angular, which I created a dynamic list of checkboxes. Because there are times which I will get the selected value from API which I need to bind to the checkboxes. 
Thus I will have the code like below

```
<div *ngFor="let b of result?.category">
                        <mat-checkbox (change)="onChangeCheckbox($event)" [value]="b.RefAccess?.accessId"
                            [checked]="b.RefAccess?.selected" [(ngModel)]="b.BoRefAccess?.selected"
                            [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
                            {{b.BoRefAccess?.accessDesc}}
                        </mat-checkbox>
                    </div>

Error "Empty expressions are not allowed ng , Parser Error: The '?.' operator cannot be used in the assignment at column 25 in [b.BoRefAccess?.selected=$event] in..."
```

My main problem now is the ngModel binding can not be optional but I need it to be optional because there are times API will give me null list item. So I not sure how to handle it.

I also came across another method which keep track on the onChange event but it will only consist checkboxes that being onChanged, those are selected is not included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elvis operator can't be used for assignment. You should declare it in a more explicit way.

Instead of

`[(ngModel)]="b.BoRefAccess?.selected"`

Use

```
[ngModel]="b.BoRefAccess?.selected" (ngModelChange)="b.BoRefAccess.selected=$event"
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! May i know whats the different between explicit way and implicit? Any article or explanation on this?

Comment: About ngModel you can check here: https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel
ngModel is the input, ngModelChange the output

Comment: now I noticed, if I try to bind null ngModel, the console will show the error TypeError: Cannot set property 'selected' of null and stop there, it will broke all my function from running, can I have a default value when the ngModel is null?

Comment: is there something like is this b.BoRefAccess. selected is null then set to false or else set to its own value?

Comment: Try this [ngModel]="b.BoRefAccess !== null ? BoRefAccess.selected : false" (ngModelChange)="b.BoRefAccess !== null ? b.BoRefAccess.selected=$event : (b.BoRefAccess = { selected: false })"

Comment: sorry mate, I found the issue happen on when I manipulate the data. I compare two array and set the selected value to true if found and vice versa. Is there any way can skip the assignment to selected value if the field is null?

Comment: Sure. Try use a *ngIf in mat-checkbox that control the value. If the value is null you could not show it.

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm thinking maybe you could create another variable to bind with ngModel. In the function onChangeCheckbox you created, you could update the value of b.RefAccess.selected if it's different from null.